# R Split data.frame using a column that represents and on/off switch

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that looks like the following:

```
a <- data.frame(cbind(x=seq(50),
                      y=rnorm(50),
                      z=c(rep(0,5),
                          rep(1,8),
                          rep(0,3),
                          rep(1,2),
                          rep(0,12),
                          rep(1,12),
                          rep(0,8))))
```

I would like to split the data.frame `a` on the column `z` but have each group as a separate `data.frame` as a member of a list i.e. in my example the first 5 rows would be the first item in the list the next 8 rows would be the next item in the list, the next 3 rows would be item after that etc. etc.

Simple factors combine all the 1s together and all the 0s together...

I'm sure that there is a simple way to do this, but it has eluded for at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `rleid` function in `data.table` [v > 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)
split(a, rleid(a$z))
# $`1`
#   x           y z
# 1 1 -0.03737561 0
# 2 2 -0.48663043 0
# 3 3 -0.98518106 0
# 4 4  0.09014355 0
# 5 5 -0.07703517 0
# 
# $`2`
#     x          y z
# 6   6  0.3884339 1
# 7   7  1.5962833 1
# 8   8 -1.3750668 1
# 9   9  0.7987056 1
# 10 10  0.3483114 1
# 11 11 -0.1777759 1
# 12 12  1.1239553 1
# 13 13  0.4841117 1
....
```

Comment: Cool new function! Thanks! Is there a non- v1.9.5 solution?

Comment: I think `rleid` looks like something this: `rleid=function(x){r=rle(x);rep(1:length(r$lengths),r$lengths)}` if you don't want to pull in `data.table`.

Comment: @CathG would you please stop being a spelling nazi :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, yes, sorry for that, can't help it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some `base R` options.

1. Using `rle`.  A variant of `rleid` function in the comments by @Spacedman

   ```
   split(a,inverse.rle(within.list(rle(a$z), values <- seq_along(values))))
   ```
2. By using `cumsum` after creating a logical index based on whether the adjacent elements are equal or not

   ```
   split(a, cumsum(c(TRUE, a$z[-1]!=a$z[-nrow(a)])))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Or, also with `cumsum`:

```
split(a, c(0, cumsum(diff(a$z) != 0)))
```