# Count changes to contents of a character vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data_frame` where a character variable `x` changes in time. I want to count the number of times it changes, and fill a new vector with this count.

```
df <- data_frame(
  x = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "b"),
  wanted = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4)
)
  x wanted
1 a      1
2 a      1
3 b      2
4 b      2
5 c      3
6 b      4
```

This is similar to, but different from `rle(df$x)`, which would return

```
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 2 2 1 1
  values : chr [1:4] "a" "b" "c" "b"
```

I could try to `rep()` that output. I have also tried this, which is awfully close, but not for reasons I can't figure out immediately:

```
 df %>% mutate( 
   try_1 = cumsum(ifelse(x == lead(x) | is.na(lead(x)), 1, 0)) 
   )
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

  x wanted try_1
1 a      1     1
2 a      1     1
3 b      2     2
4 b      2     2
5 c      3     2
6 b      4     3
```

It seems like there should be a function that does this directly, that I just haven't found in my experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this `dplyr` code:

```
df %>%
  mutate(try_1 = cumsum(ifelse(x != lag(x) | is.na(lag(x)), 1, 0)))

  x wanted try_1
1 a      1     1
2 a      1     1
3 b      2     2
4 b      2     2
5 c      3     3
6 b      4     4
```

Yours was saying: increment the count if a value is the same as the following row's value, or if the following row's value is NA.

This says: increment the count if the variable on this row either is different than the one on the previous row, or if there wasn't one on the previous row (e.g., row 1).

Comment: You created with data.frame(), the original post created with data_frame(). Looks like this works on a character variable, not a factor.

Comment: Yep if I use the `data.frame` from your post but add in `df$x <- as.character(df$x)` it works for me.

Comment: You could shorten the code `mutate(df, try_1 = cumsum(x!=lag(x)|is.na(lag(x))))` as `TRUE/FALSE` will coerce to numeric values `1/0` by cumsum

Comment: `default` option in `lag` can be also used as well `mutate(df, try_1 = cumsum(x!=lag(x, default=1)))`

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.9.5
setDT(df)[, wanted := rleid(x)][]
#    x wanted
#1: a      1
#2: a      1
#3: b      2
#4: b      2
#5: c      3
#6: b      4
```

Or a `base R` option would be

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(as.character(df$x)),
                          values<- seq_along(values)))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 4
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "b"))
```

Comment: Ah. What I actually did, to avoid bringing in `data.table`, was to copy the code `rleid=function(x){r=rle(x);rep(1:length(r$lengths),r$lengths)}` from [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122618/r-split-data-frame-using-a-column-that-represents-and-on-off-switch#comment46471954_29122728)

Comment: @gregmacfarlane That works too, But, `rleid` is a nice wrapper function

Comment: Yeah, it is a nice function. In fact, it's a lot like what I was thinking in terms of wrangling with the `rle()` output. But for my purposes just including that function in my script is easier than bringing in `data.table` and worrying about name conflicts.

Comment: `rleid()` also works with more than 1 column (and is written in C for speed). @gregmacfarlane, what name conflicts are you worrying about?

Comment: `last()`, mostly. I realize that I can be explicit or load `dplyr` afterwards. But for our application it's easier to just not use `data.table`.